# I'm trying to create a bot and I would like all my messages to be contained with in the same div in JS

Tags: javascript, forms, chat

So I am Creating a chatbot and right now my text is appearing as I type it but it is not all appearing in the same div. After the first message is sent the rest of them appear below the input form.

I tried applying the same element that I was using at the top button but that still wasn't working. because it was making the initial message disappear. I would like all the messages to stay present.

```
var btnClick = function(text) {
  counter++;
    if (counter == 1) {
        document.getElementById("upDateText").innerText
        let newElement = document.createElement("h1");
        newElement =  = "I am " + text + "!";
        newElement.style.textAlign = "right";
        newElement.innerText = "Hi " + text + "!";
        document.body.appendChild(newElement);
        createHobbies();
      } else if (counter == 2) {
        let newElement = document.createElement("h1");
        let hobbies = 'your hobies here';
        newElement.innerText =
          "that is so cool that you like" + hobbies + " can we be friends"; // your "hobies" is not defined!
        document.body.appendChild(newElement);
      } 

  if (form.inputbox.value === "") {
    let newElement = document.createElement("h1");
    newElement.style.color = "red";
    newElement.innerText = "sorry bout that";
    document.body.appendChild(newElement);
  }
};
```

Comment: You are appending all your elements to the body `document.body.appendChild(...)` if you want them to be put into a div then you need to append them to that div not the body

Comment: I meant the div with the id "upDateText"

Comment: just did it worked! Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just change the method from `body` to `getElementById("upDateText")`

```
var btnClick = function(text) {
  counter++;

  if (counter == 1) {
    document.getElementById("upDateText").innerText = "I am " + text + "!";
    let newElement = document.createElement("h1");
    newElement.style.textAlign = "right";
    newElement.innerText = "Hi " + text + "!";

    document.getElementById("upDateText").appendChild(newElement);
    createHobbies();
  } else if (counter == 2) {
    let newElement = document.createElement("h1");
    let hobbies = 'your hobies here';
    newElement.innerText =
      "that is so cool that you like" + hobbies + " can we be friends"; // your "hobies" is not defined!
    document.getElementById("upDateText").appendChild(newElement);
  } 

  else if (form.inputbox.value === "") {
    let newElement = document.createElement("h1");
    newElement.style.color = "red";
    newElement.innerText = "sorry bout that";
    document.getElementById("upDateText").appendChild(newElement);
  }
};
```